# Problematic References after Get Latest Version

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, version-control, azure-devops

I check in a project that builds & runs fine on one computer, and then "Get Latest Version" from another. When I build & run on the second computer, I get errors like:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Cors, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've fixed this once by removing & adding back all references, but I can't be doing this every time I change setups. Why is it not pulling a complete project definition from version control?

If I delete all the files and download from TFS from scratch, on build the packages don't restore. If I run `Update-Package`, then I get the error: `The given key was not present in the dictionary.` Not sure what's causing that.

#### Update

Here's an example of the issue: I have Newtonsoft included via nuget, and it appears in the References list, but I'm being told it `Cannot resolve symbol Newtonsoft`, as per image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you **work with one XAML build definition**, there are some steps (described [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build)) you need to follow in order to have these NuGet packages restored during the VSO (TFS) build process.

1. Add following items to the solution. (Content of the nuget.config and .tfignore file can be found [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build))

[image]

2. Add one build.proj file under the root path of the solution folder. (Content of the build.proj file can be found [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build))
3. Create one folder named **tools** under the root path of the solution folder. Create **NuGet** sub-folder under **tools** folder, download and save [nuget.exe](https://www.nuget.org/nuget.exe) under tools\NuGet path.
4. Check in **nuget.config**, **.tfignore**, **build.proj** and **tools\NuGet\nuget.exe** into TFS version control.
5. Modify the build definition to choose to build the build.proj file.
   [image]

Then you will have NuGet packages restored successfully during the TFS build process.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET5, I don't think that applies?

Comment: @Sean, what's the version of our Visual Studio? VS2013 or VS2015?

Comment: @Sean, I modified my above reply, please follow my steps to make your build successful.